# how to fix "Not enough memory resources are available to complete this operation" asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ocr, office-interop, modi

I am using loop for my images so I can get multiple images at a time and extract the written data from those images, I am using MODI for my OCR in Visual studio to extract the written data but my problem is ...

after one loop "Not enough memory resources are available to complete this operation" this error appears and only one image is saved in my database, I have tried taking, string builder, string list, and many other helps from internet but still not able to solve my problem. I am stuck at this code for past week

Please help!! if anyone can..

I want to download images in loop to my database and at the same time do Optical Character Recognition.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The decade-old server side Office automation is not worth the while to discuss, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2

Comment: Posting an image is encouraged if it helps understanding the issue better. But please don´t post code or error messages as images only. We can´t copy and test the code properly. [edit] your question and add that information.

Comment: How many times do you call it if call it do you wait to one finished or not? If you callit many times try call dispose on the image. If you dont wait to one finished try wait one after the other. Could be something else

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2) article.

Instead, consider using any components designed for the server-side execution and that don't required Office on the system.